# Print biblatex bibliography without labels

Tags: biblatex

my question is rather similar to this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61052/displaying-bibtex-item-in-references-without-label), except that I'm using `biblatex` and not `bibtex`. I searched the manual and TE, but I can find only answers how to use a custom label provided by `biblatex`, but not how to completely avoid it. Thank you!

Here is a MWE. Basically, I'm using two bibliographies: one "normal" at the end, and one "special" in the middle of the document, containing only entries having the keyword. For this special bibliography, I would like to avoid the label.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[sorting=nty, maxnames=99, firstinits=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{database.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{key}
\printbibliography[heading=none, sorting=ydnt, keyword=SelectFromHugeBibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without a proper MWE we can just guess (what style do you use?). But a `bibstyle=authortitle` might help?

Answer (score 6):

Normally, one would just choose a bibliography style that does not have labels, such as `bibstyle=authortitle`.
In your case with two bibliographies, however, that is not really feasible.

You can define a custom `bibenvironment` that suppresses the labelling and use that for the mid-document bibliography.

We can just take the standard `authortitle` definition as basis

```
\defbibenvironment{midbib}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

of course you can change all that to your liking (see §3.7.7 *Bibliography Headings and Environments*, p. 90 and §4.2.2 *Bibliography Environments*, p. 148 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

For your special bibliography, all you do is specify the special environment via the `env` option (`env=midbib`; see §3.7.2 *The Bibliography*, p. 83 of the [`biblatex` docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf))

```
\printbibliography[heading=none, sorting=ydnt, env=midbib, keyword=primary]
```

The standard environment used by `\printbibliography` without an explicit `env` option retains the labels as expected.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=nty, maxnames=99, firstinits=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{midbib}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}
\nocite{wilde,aristotle:physics}

\printbibliography[heading=none, sorting=ydnt, env=midbib, keyword=primary]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I will provide 50 points for that as soon as possible :-)