# Displaying BibTex item Bibliography without label

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, labels

Similar to this [previous tex.stackexchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61052/displaying-bibtex-item-in-references-without-label) I would like to remove the labels from the bibliography but within the "report" document class. When injecting the following code in my preamble :

```
    \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{}%
           {\labelwidth=0pt
            \labelsep=0pt
            \leftmargin1.5em
            \itemindent=-1.5em
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            }%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
\makeatother
\usepackage{breakcites}
```

My bibliography is named "References" instead of "Bibliography" *and* its entry is removed from the table of contents.

Comment: Since your `thebibliography` environment of the `report` document class contains the macro `\refname`, have you considered running `\renewcommand\refname{Bibliography}`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Now there is still one thing bothering me. How do I make the Bibliography appears in the table of content ?

Comment: See, e.g., [Bibliography in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71129/5001)

Comment: I did tried already the 2 workarounds proposed but it doesn't seems to work, maybe I could share you the document on which I work ?

Comment: Yes, by all means, feel free to edit your query to state that you've tried so far. You're probably aware that statements such as "it doesn't seem to work" are not actionable. So, do be precise about what it is that you're trying to achieve, what you've tried to do so far, and what's "not working."

Comment: Thank you very much, here is a link to an editable copy of my work https://www.overleaf.com/5487496397hnpdmjstjsns
Thank you for your advices

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a working overleaf account. By the way, I hear that the folks on the overleaf help desk are really good.

Comment: Ok thanks for what you've helped me to achieve so far